# Zend Framework 2 - Wrapping $this->content with another layout

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to create a wrapper for the $this->content of a specific Module.

What I have is a main layout (All the modules will follow this layout) which builds the base layout with headers and footers, etc.  These will stay the same across all the Modules.

However I want to have modules with a custom layout for their body content.  I.e. for custom nav bars, etc.

So with the following structure:

```
module
  / ModuleName
    / view
      / layout
        / modulelayout.phtml
      / modulename
        / index
          / index.phtml
view
  / layout
    / layout.phtml
```

The /view/layout/layout.phtml:

```
<?= $this->doctype(); ?>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>...</header>

        <div id='body'>
            <?= $this->content; ?>
        </div>

           <footer>...</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

The /module/ModuleName/view/layout/modulelayout.phtml:

```
<div>...</div>

<div>
    <?= $this->content; ?>
</div>
```

The /module/ModuleName/view/modulename/index/index.phtml:

```
Hello World
...
```

So I want all of the actions inside of ModuleName (their $this->content that is displayed), to be wrapped with the layout from modulelayout.phtml.

I created a listener on the dispatch event of a controller to capture it for all controller actions:

```
public function onBootstrap($e) {
    $app = $e->getApplication();
    $app->getEventManager()
        ->getSharedManager()
            ->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController', 'dispatch', array($this, 'dispatchControllerStrategy'));
}
```

**Now I need to know how to I retain the base layout, and add my module layout as a wrapper?**

```
public function dispatchControllerStrategy($e) {
    $controller = $e->getTarget();

    $layout = $controller->layout();

    $wrapper = new ViewModel();
    $wrapper->setTemplate('layout/modulelayout');

    $layout->addChild($wrapper, 'content');
}
```

^^^ The adding of the child layout does not seem to wrap $this->content in any way, and the child layout does not render.  To bring it all together, this is what I expect the final source to look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>...</header>

        <div id='body'>
            <div>...</div>

            <div>
              Hello World
              ...
            </div>
        </div>

           <footer>...</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think I am getting closer to my answer.  It appears that my action view gets added as a child to the base layout (layout/layout), not as a child of my wrapper layout (layout/modulelayout).  So I need to figure out how to attach the action layout to the wrapper layout inside of the dispatch (I don't want to return a newView inside each action).

Comment: I think you are looking for this https://github.com/juriansluiman/SlmThreeStepView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after a lot of messing around I finally found my solution.  And it appears that comment of SlmThreeStepView user2257808 was what I wanted to begin with, but my solution fit my need exactly so I am just going to share it here:

I stopped worrying about trying to modify the layout on controller dispatch and focused on the View with the EVENT_RENDERER_POST event:

```
->attach('Zend\View\View', \Zend\View\ViewEvent::EVENT_RENDERER_POST, array($this, 'renderViewStrategy'));
```

I then modify my model on render:

```
private $renderdedOuterView = false;
public function renderViewStrategy($e) {
    if ($this->renderdedOuterView) {
        return;
    } else {
        $this->renderdedOuterView = true;
    }

    $layout = $e->getModel();

    $children = $layout->getChildren();
    $layout->clearChildren();

    $wrapper = new ViewModel();
    $wrapper->setTemplate('layout/modulelayout');
    $wrapper->addChild($children[0], 'content');

    $layout->addChild($wrapper, 'content');
}
```

I used $renderedOuterView to only do any render modification for the main layout.

Then for the main layout, I get the Model, and grab the attached child which would be the layout for the current action.

I then clear the main template of that child and add my wrapper in its place.  Then as a child of my wrapper, I add the layout for the current action I had just removed from the main template.

My not be the best option, but this solution fits exactly what I was trying to accomplish with my question.

**UPDATE**

I wanted to add that I found out another issue.
All the onBootstraps for each Module get called, regardless if they are the active module.

This was causing a different module to get this layout.  The change was adding an EVENT_DISPATCH first:

```
$evtMgr = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
$evtMgr->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'handleEventStrategy'));
```

Then inside of the handleEventStrategy, I check to make sure that the active Module is the module's bootstrap that is being called.  If it is, then I attach the EVENT_RENDER_POST and use the renderViewStrategy that I had defined.

If the active module is not the module with the render view strategy, the if condition will fail and no other module will get that modified layout.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this module: https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpModuleLayouts

And then add the config in your module config file

```
array(
    'module_layouts' => array(
        'ModuleName' => 'layout/some-layout',
    ),
);
```

Comment: I had seen it, but all it is doing is changing the main layout for each module.  I want to keep the main layout the same and add a layout wrapper to the output of $this->content.