# How can I inject additional child view into layout, that modules can override?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-view, zend-navigation, zend-layout

In my layout I would like an additional `child view` to render a menu. So in my layout I have;

```
<?php echo $this->menu; ?>
```

Then in my `config` under the view manager `template_map` key I have;

```
'navigation/menu' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/navigation/menu.phtml',
```

How can I create an event listener that will inject my view template into the layout. And how could modules override this to use their own view template?

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18003563/1386551)